# how can remove Plugin settings stored in wordpress database?

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins

I try to totally remove Podcasting Plugin by TSG since it generated thousand of useless lines in its settings and in my blog home page.
But if deleting its files is not enough since all settings are stored in wordpress database options table.

Mu question is: how could I delete all these settings in order to start from scratch a new installation?

Thanks.

Comment: if all these records have any common prefix, etc.. you can delete them by using sql query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into the database directly.

If you're using a MySQL administration tool (e.g. phpmyadmin), go there, search for the settings that it has changed (e.g. if the plugin changed a the web address for the site, you can manually change it back to what you want).

If you don't happen to know exactly what it changed, since it may be difficult to exactly know, if you have saved a previous version of the MySQL database, you could start over and import the old .sql file that you have saved.